# PHP MAIL Body of email not being included

Tags: php

I have a script to email out attachments, but i cannot get the body of the email to be included it just sends blank

I have tried different charsets, UTF8 and the ISO8559

I tried

```
"Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"utf-8\n" . 

"Content-Type: text/plaintext; charset=\"utf-8\n" .
```

But made no difference....

```
$name        = "XXXXXXXX";
$email       = "XXXXXX";
$to          = "XXXXXXXXX";
$from        = "XXXXXXXX";
        $subject     = "Thank you for your payment";
    $mainMessage = "ANy text here to send in email";
    $fileatt     = "inv/".$invRef.".pdf";
    $fileatttype = "application/pdf";
    $fileattname = $invRef.".pdf";
    $headers = "From: $from";



    // File
    $file = fopen($fileatt, 'rb');
    $data = fread($file, filesize($fileatt));
    fclose($file);
    // This attaches the file
$semi_rand     = md5(time());
$mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";
$headers      .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" .
"Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" .
" boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";

$message = "" .
"-{$mime_boundary}\n" .
"Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"utf-8\n" .
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n" .
$mainMessage  . "\n";

$data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
$message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
"Content-Type: {$fileatttype};\n" .
" name=\"{$fileattname}\"\n" .
"Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" .
" filename=\"{$fileattname}\"\n" .
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" .
$data . "\n\n" .
"-{$mime_boundary}-\n";
```

I have tried other mailers such as swift & simple external libraries but they caused me more headaches for other reasons

This has got me the closest to sending the email

The attachment works, the email sends, subject is fine.

Just nothing in the body

Comment: May not solve it, but in the string, you lack one escaped double quote. Think it should read: `"Content-Type: text/plaintext; charset=\"utf-8\"\n"`

Comment: Tried that, didnt make a difference :( Thanks anyway